# RegEx for matching the last occurrence of a tag

Tags: regex, go, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to extract the contact link from the HTML code below. I have tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
\"([^\"]*)\"(.*?)?\>(Kontakt)
```

and some part HTML-code:

```
<li id="cc-nav-view-2315645627" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/" data-link-title="Start" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current jmd-nav__link--current">Start</a>
</li>
<li id="cc-nav-view-2315645625" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/öffnungszeiten-schließzeiten/" data-link-title="Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten">Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten</a>
</li>
<li id="cc-nav-view-2316315025" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
   <a href="/flyer/" data-link-title="Flyer">Flyer</a>
</li>
<li id="cc-nav-view-2315732425" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/anfahrt/" data-link-title="Anfahrt">Anfahrt</a></li>
<li id="cc-nav-view-2315645825" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0">
    <a href="/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/" data-link-title="Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren">Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren</a>
</li>
```

I need to get the last `a href` occurrence with the contact link, but regexp returns the full string.

Check this [link](https://regex101.com/r/fSbnXi/2).

Comment: Are you trying to extract the whole HTML element `<a href="/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/" data-link-title="Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren">Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren</a>` or only the text inside?

Comment: @Abdullah  I have to get only "/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/"

Comment: fyi: it's "vereinbaren" not "verbeinaren"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/VQJZxl/1) might help you to design a desired one to do so:

```
(.*)(<a href=")([A-z0-9-\/]+)(".*)
```

It swipe from beginning using `(.*)` to the last `href`, then you can add any boundary that you wish to capture that target URL.

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how it works:

[image]

I'm not so sure, if you want just the URL or the entire tag. If you wish to get the entire tag, then the expression can be simply modified to something [similar to](https://regex101.com/r/qO0L3c/1):

```
(.*)((<a href=")(.*)(\<\/a\>))
```

Comment: The graph has a different pattern than the suggested pattern. And did you mean `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-z]` because that matches [more characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret).

Comment: @Emma, thank you. Now it looks like (.*)((<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"(.*?)?\>(Kontakte?)(.*)(\<\/a\>)))